# k-dimensional Representations Factoring Through Subgroups

Tags: representation-theory

The 1-dimensional representations of a group $G$ factor through the abelianization $G / G'$ (for a proof see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785244/showing-1-dim-representations-factor-through-g-g)).

Do the $k$-dimensional representations factor through a different subgroup of $G$?

It seems like the answer is no (else I would have found it before).

Comment: Your question is somehow incomplete. The reason that the $1$-dimensional case factors through the commutator is that the target group in that case is abelian, hence the commutator subgroup is in the kernel of the map. Without this assumption then again you have somehow this situation, if the representation isn't faithful. It's straightforward from the 1st isomorphism theorem of groups.

Comment: The new target group is $GL(k, \mathbb{C})$, and the question is whether the kernel of every homomorphism $\pi : G \to GL(k, \mathbb{C})$ contains some reasonably-defined subgroup. Does this help?

Comment: For example, perhaps you might say degree-3 representations factor through $G / G'''$ i.e. $G'''$ is in all kernels of homomorphisms to $GL(3, \mathbb{C})$. But this doesn't work because $A_5$ has a degree-3 irreducible representation (with trivial kernel), but $A_5^{(k)} = A_5$ for all $k$.